# Jersey web services multiple formats

Tags: xml, json, jersey

In following method:

```
@GET

@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})

@Path("{id}")

public String getMessage(@PathParam("username") String username,

    @PathParam("id") int id,
    @QueryParam("format") String format) {

 return "test";
}
```

how do I return the the data in the specific format determined by the format query parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found this suggested solution](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Representation-Type-Determined-by-Query-Parameter-td4700733.html):

> Jersey supports URI-based conneg using
>   a suffix at the end of the path.
>
> You can declare in your web.xml a
>   mapping of suffix to media type:
>   https://jersey.dev.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#PROPERTY_MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS
>
> if you want to do the same using a
>   query parameter you could write a
>   Jersey request filter that does
>   similar things to the suffix filter:
>
> http://fisheye4.atlassian.com/browse/jersey/trunk/jersey/jersey-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/UriConnegFilter.java?r=HEAD
>
> which modifies the accept header based
>   on the suffix value.